# Bluetooth, two sources to two different ouputs simultaneously

Tags: bluetooth-5

i want to play sound from two different sources to two different Bluetooth simultaneously. Can this be done? With Bluetooth-5 you can connect two speakers simultaneously, can i target my output to one of the channels.

- Source a, a sound player plays voice A to speaker A
- Source b, a sound player plays voice B to speaker B

Any recommendations regarding software / hardware

It will be build in a app for android / iphone